# Showing that two Banach spaces are homeomorphic when their dimensions are equal.

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. It is quite easy to show that they are homeomorphic when their dimensions are finite and equal.

However, I find it difficult to show that they are homeomorphic when their dimensions are *infinite* and equal. Here, the statement that their dimensions are equal must mean that a basis of $X$ and a basis of $Y$ have the same cardinality. (I know that any vector space has a basis by Zorn's Lemma.)

Could anyone help me how to show that they are homeomorphic when their dimensions are infinite?

Comment: Are you sure it is valid for infinite dimensional spaces. Take $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ equipped with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$ with $\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}=\int_0^1(|f(t)|+|f'(t)|)dt$

Comment: @marwalix, all separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are homeomorphic although the homeomorphism is usually not linear.

Comment: They are homeomorphic iff they have the same topological density (e.g. both separable). But the proof is quite long. It's relatively easy for the standard $\ell_p$ spaces etc.

Answer (score 10):

Let me comment on that question. The algebraic dimension for Banach spaces is actually rather useless. It seems that the correct dimension should be

$${\rm correct\, dimension} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}\dim X,& X\text{ is finite-dimensional},\\ \min |A|\colon A\subseteq X\text{ is dense},& \text{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

> **Theorem**. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces with the same dimension, as defined above. Then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

References:

1. M. I. Kadets, [Proof of the topological equivalence of all separable
   infinite-dimensional Banach spaces](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01075865#page-1), *Functional Analysis and Its
   Applications*, **1** (1967), 53–62.
2. H. Toruńczyk, [Characterizing Hilbert space topology](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm111/fm11135.pdf), *Fund.
   Math.* **111** (1981), 247–262.

Comment: (1) Stupid seems a bit excessive. (2) Why not define it as the least $|A|$ for which $\operatorname{span}(A)$ is dense in $X$? You get both the vector space connection, and the finite dimensional case as well. Otherwise dimension is not even related to the vector space structure. Just the metric structure.

Comment: Asaf, they are the same.

Comment: I know they are the same. I meant that the definition I suggested don't treat Banach spaces just as metric spaces, but as actual vector spaces. (And I stand by the first part of the comment that "stupid" is somewhat excessive here.)

Comment: I believe that for non-separable (and so automatically infinite-dimensional, in whatever sense) Banach spaces $X,Y$ we also have that $d(X) = d(Y)$ iff $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, where $d(X)$ is (as usual) the minimal cardinality of a dense subset. I think it's in Bessaga and Peczynski. It's quite non-trivial :)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, thank you, you are completely right. Corrected.

Answer (score 8):

Both $\ell_2$ and $\ell_\infty$ have the same algebraic dimension of $2^{\aleph_0}$. But they are clearly not homeomorphic, since only one separable.

Comment: I think the conclusion of this discussion is "any two infinite dimensional Banach spaces with same dimension may not be homeomorphic." Is it?

Comment: That is correct.