# Banach space and Hilbert space topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be a Banach space. It is not necessarily true that
there exists a Hilbert space $H$ *linearly isometric* to $B$.

However, is it true that there exists a Hilbert space $H$
*homeomorphic* to $B$?

Comment: If $B$ is separable, then yes. All separable Banach Spaces are homeomorphic. So homeomorphic to $\ell^2$

Comment: @user124910 We can extend this to non-separable as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but this is quite a deep result. Two infinite-dimensional Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic iff $d(X)=d(Y)$, where the density $d(X)$ is the minimal size of a dense subset of $X$.

So any separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ (and even to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, because the result extends to locally convex completely metrisable TVS's as well). And for higher densities we have Hilbert spaces $\ell_2(\kappa)$ as models. Finite dimensional we only have the $\mathbb{R}^n$ up to homeomorphism, which are already Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Do you know of a reference with the proof of this?

Comment: @user156213 [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312845/showing-that-two-banach-spaces-are-homeomorphic-when-their-dimensions-are-equal) post has a reference.