# Are any two isomorphic normed linear spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism

We know that any two finite-dimensional linear spaces (over a same field) of same dimension is isomorphic.

**Qn.1** Are any two finite-dimensional normed linear spaces (over a same field) with same dimension **isometrically** isomorphic?

**Qn.2** Are any two isomorphic normed linear spaces are **homeomorphic**?

Thanks in advance. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer to Qn 1. $\mathbb R^{2}$ with Euclidean norm is not isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the max norm.

Answer (score 3):

1. No. The two dimensional normed space whose "unit ball" is a square is not isometric to the Euclidean two dimensional space.
2. Any two finite dimensional normed linear spaces (of the same dimension) are homeomorphic, because any two convex,compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interior are homeomorphic one to another.

The proofs are not too difficult.

For infinite dimension there are positive results, too. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312845/showing-that-two-banach-spaces-are-homeomorphic-when-their-dimensions-are-equal).

Comment: Can you provide proof (link/something) on the claim "Any two finite dimensional normed linear spaces (of the same dimension) are homeomorphic?"